# vim regex increment all numbers by 1

Tags: regex, vim

I have a prepared statement in java that i am adding an argument to the front of.
Long story short, I have to take a ton of set methods and increment their first argument by 1.

I'd like a quick way to do a search and replace matching all numbers, and then increment them by one.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
%s/\d\+/\=(submatch(0)+1)/g
```

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_an_expression_in_substitute_command

Comment: yup.  Shouldn't need the parens around the whole expression, though.  `\=submatch(0)+1` should do the trick.

Comment: Wow, those `\=` substitutions really kick ass... That's what I love vim for: You get all those general, and simple to use tools, and can freely combine them to great effect. Unix principle at its best :-)

Comment: I also wanted to mention how it would be used with a capture group: `%s/int i = \(\d\+\);/\='int i = '.(submatch(1)+1).';'/g`

Answer (score 17):

The only regex you need to know is `\d`.

```
:g/\d/exe "normal! \<C-A>"
```

Comment: How do you make this global (like the `g` modifier for `:s`). Also, you need to escape your `+`

Comment: @user606723 :g is by definition global

Comment: This subtly answers the question even better because only the first number on the line is incremented (the first arg as mentioned in the question), whereas the accepted answer will increment all numbers everywhere.

Comment: @Matthew Is there a way to make this work on the entire line ?

Comment: @Hritik the accepted answer above should do that: `:%s/\d\+/\=(submatch(0)+1)/g`. If you only want a single line, remove the `%` or if you want a specific range of lines, change it to the range you want. For example, for lines 5-10 it would be `:5,10s/\d\+/\=(submatch(0)+1)/g`.

Answer (score 1):

I mis-interpreted the question as to be asking how to increments a number by one on each line, i.e.

```
var1
var1
var1
```

to be

```
var1
var2
var3
```

So I thought I'd post an answer for that.  The [link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_an_expression_in_substitute_command) @user606723 provided shows that you can do that with (say between lines 1 and 3):

```
:let counter=0|1,3g//let counter=counter+1|s/^/\=counter."\t"
```