# vi editor: :s How to add constant to number in pattern

Tags: vi

I have a text file in which every line looks like this:

```
abcd123efgh[4]
abcd456efgh[5]
abcd789ijkl[6]
abcd101efgh[7]
abcd123efgh[8]
```

I want to add a constant to all numbers inside [], using vi editor. 
For example, if the constant is 15, I want to change the lines above to:

```
abcd123efgh[19]
abcd456efgh[20]
abcd789ijkl[21]
abcd101efgh[22]
abcd123efgh[23]
```

I found

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420797/vim-regex-increment-all-numbers-by-1
```

which changes all the numbers in a file, but couldn't make the solution work for certain numbers only
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ctrl+a (`\<C-a>`) sequence for increment the next number which is found in the line.

So if you are with your cursor at a `[` you can type 15 and then ctrl+a and it adds 15 to the number inside the `[]`.

If you want to use this for behaviour for all numbers in [] for your file you can make something like this:

`:g/\v\[[0-9]+\]/execute "normal f[15\<C-a>"`

So, you use global to execute a command on multiple lines.

The regex `\v\[[0-9]+\]` defines the lines which are effected.
Where `\v` is a modifier which stands for very magic (use real regex syntax)

Then we are searching for `[]` with any numbers in it.

If we found such lines the following command will be executed:
`execute "normal f[15\<C-a>"`

`execute` function is mainly just to make ctrl+a possible with the sequence `\<C-a>`.

`normal` stands for executing command in vim normal mode.
`f[` finds the next `[` symbol in the line.
And finally as already mentioned we increment 15 times with `15\<C-a>`.